# can the default binder deserialize complex JSON obj?

Tags: c#, ajax, json

I want to send a JSON object from the client to

an action on a MVC controller.

Something like:

```
{ A: {1,2,3} , B: 3, C: {d:{1,2,3} ,4}} }
```

Can I create an object with the same struct and the default binder

will know to deserialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Have a look at this article: [Post Complex JavaScript Objects to ASP.NET MVC Controllers](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/post-complex-javascript-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-controllers/)

Download the source code provided on this page and make use of the $.postify jquery plugin.